# 208x240 buck boost transformer putting out ~260v

Tags: well-pump, transformer

I recently installed a buck-boost transformer in one of our buildings with 208Y/120v service to support a 1hp submersible well-pump rated for 230v single-phase.

The transformer is a [GE 9T51B0158](https://www.geempower.com/ecatalog/ec/EN_NA/p/9T51B0158) which is labeled for 208v primary x 240v secondary, up to 500va.

Per the label diagram, I connected 208v nominal (210v measured at the transformer) to X1 & X2, tied H2 to H3, and then took a meter reading at H1 & H4 before connecting to the well-pump control. I measured 259v at H1 & H4, unloaded. Is there some reason to expect this kind of over-voltage? Would you expect the secondary to drop down closer to 240v under some load? Or is it more likely that I have either misunderstood the wiring diagram or acquired a dud unit?

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Thanks,

Dan

Comment: With a Wye I don't usually see big swings, 500va is a bit small in my opinion for a 1 hp pump, I think you will see the voltage drop quite a bit with a load.

Comment: @EdBeal - Thanks for your thoughts.  My understanding is that VA on Buck Boost transformers is measured on the voltage differential, so 208-to-240v would be 32v, or a max of 15.63 amps @ 500VA.  I can't see the nameplate on the pump motor, but I don't expect it would show a running current over 10 amps...

Comment: I just realized you were boosting from 208 to 240 you have the calculation. Right but the motor is going to draw close to 24 amps at startup.

Comment: Well the VA is the value volts x amps. Since yo with motor loads the draw is normally 3x FLA (full load amperage) or more on start up. The NEC has table 430.248 for motor amperages. A 1 hp 230v motor is rated a 8 amps a 208v motor 8.8 that's why I said the transformer was a bit small was not thinking of boost.

Comment: This isn't adding up. First off, that is not a buck boost transformer. That is a standard power or control transformer with a 208V primary and 120/240 secondary. Actual buck/boost transformers have very low voltage secondaries meant to buck or boost the line voltage by tens of volts. And ~260V is exactly what I would expect if someone wired a transformer with a 208V primary to a 240V supply. The difference between 208 and 240V is 13.3% so 240+13.3% is about 272V, higher than your 260 but if we substitute 230V, you end with almost exactly 260V which is possible if taps are present.

Comment: @MisterTea I came to the same conclusion this morning.  I've ordered the correct unit (32v buck/boost), as noted below.  However, the 259v on the secondary isn't coming from a 240v supply.  My line voltage at the building is 208v nominal, 210v as measured at the primary.  My thinking is that the secondary measured high because it was unloaded and probably would have come down into the expected range once putting a load on...  Thanks for your input - if I hadn't already figured it out, you might have saved me from smoking that pump, hanging 300' underground...

Comment: @dewhite04 Glad to be of help. The 32v buck/boost is exactly what you need. Just be sure it is able to handle the motor load, the NEC says 8A for 1HP at 240V but will vary in reality (6 - 9A depending on the motor design). A 500VA buck-boost transformer will fit the bill. 250VA is too little low and the high current draw across the secondary will cause the voltage to sag during starting. And be sure to check the polarity, you don't want start/run the motor on 176V!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### That transformer is awful small

Your transformer is *not* a buck-boost transformer as you assumed it to be -- instead, it's a standard (isolating dry type) transformer with a 120/240V primary and a 208V secondary.  As a result, its windings are handling full power, which means that since it's a 500VA unit, it can only handle 2A at 240V coming out.  I'd expect it to overheat quite severely trying to handle the 8FLA@240VAC of a 1HP motor.

### As to the high output

I would check the *input* voltage -- it sounds like the input is on the high side, and doubly so because there will usually be a bit of [*turns ratio compensation*](http://apps.geindustrial.com/publibrary/checkout/Transformer2?TNR=White%20Papers|Transformer2|generic) on the design secondary side that acts in the *opposite* direction from what you are describing in a backfed application such as yours.  However, it should drop to a more normal value under a reference load.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful input.  I came also to this conclusion on my own this morning while studying GE's catalog.  I'm really glad to have figured this out before connecting a submersible pump, hanging ~300' underground.  I have ordered a similarly sized 32v buck/boost transformer [GE 9T51B0128](https://www.geempower.com/ecatalog/ec/EN_NA/p/9T51B0128) to suit my needs.  I'm now left wondering what would be a good use-case for a dedicated 208x240 transformer that can only carry a ~2A load...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me that you have boosted your power by 20% (210*1.2=252). Your input voltage is constantly changing plus or minus 5% so your output will not be exactly 252V.

I don't know how sensitive your pump motor is and if it would take that high of a boost. Motors do like to run a little hot but you would need to check with the manufacturer to see if 259V would fit in the range. A tolerance might be listed somewhere in the paperwork or on the motor. Let's say your odds are about 50/50.

I have attached the buck/boost diagram from my old ugly's if you want to try one of those. The 5% increase and the 10% increase are on the far right first and second respectively.
[image]

If this doesn't help GE should have a similar set of diagrams with the xfmr.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks for your response.  What you're saying makes sense, but I'm afraid I've got a specialty unit that is only designed to yield a set amount of buck or boost.  I'm attaching GE's diagram, and info label.  It appears the taps are more limited and can only be wired in two ways (to make 240v or 120v from 208v, or of course, vice-versa).  I'm now thinking that some of the windings in the transformer may be leaking voltage, causing the ratio to become skewed.  Alternatively, I can hope that presenting a load to the secondary might drop the actual voltage delivered into the desired range.

Comment: Edit:  It seems I don't have enough reputation to post images, but I can link to them.
 
See below:

[label](http://dewhite.xepher.net/forums/stackexchange/buck.boost.label.jpg)

[diagram](http://dewhite.xepher.net/forums/stackexchange/buck.boost.diagram.png)

Comment: The poster doesn't have a buck-boost, just a standard 500VA control transformer.

Comment: I wanted to add one more comment to your reply, saying that I appreciate the information you provided.  I thought it best to select one of the other replies as "best answer" because it could really save someone a headache if they were making the same mistake I almost did, but your post was also very informative and put my mind on the track to understanding what I was doing incorrectly.  **Thanks!**